# Definition of Partially Ordered Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Enderton, Elements of Set Theory, page 189 just above Theorem 7J mentions that if $<$ is an ordering on $A$ and $C$ is a proper subset of $A$ then $<$ is technically not an ordering on $C$ as $<$ is not on $C$. Similarly, the way that partially ordered sets (or any other types of ordered sets) are defined, if $\langle A,<\rangle$ is a partially ordered set, then $\langle C,<\rangle$ is not necessarily a partially ordered set. Instead $\langle C,< \cap\ C \times C\rangle$ is. Enderton mentions how the need to modify the order for a subset is inconvenient and clumsy and makes up a new notation to compensate.

So, I was wondering why, if $A$ is a set and $R$ a relation, we require $R \subseteq A \times A$ in the definition of, say a partially ordered set? Why don't we just say $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a partially ordered set iff $R \cap A \times A$ is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive? That way if, for example, $\langle A,R\rangle $ is a poset and $C \subseteq A$ then $\langle C,R\rangle$ is a poset.  I know that defintions are whatever you want them to be, but good defintions help with formulation of concise theorems and simplifying notation. Other than being out-of-step with existing defintions, is there anything obviously wrong with this approach?

Comment: One reason is that it's convenient when working with $R$ on $A$ to know that it only contains pairs of elements of $A$ and not other junk. Also if you know where $A$ "lives" in the cumulative hierarchy of sets, then you know where $R$ lives since $R\in P(A\times A)$.

Answer (score 1):

You’re talking about what are called **induced subposets**. For a poset $P=(X,\leq)$ and any $Y\subseteq X$, the subposet of $P$ **induced** by $Y$ is $Q=(Y,\leq’)$ where $\leq’=\leq\cap(Y\times Y)$.

We wouldn’t call $\leq$ a partial order on any $Y \neq X$—or even a relation on $Y$—because it’s extremely useful to have a term that means “a subset of $Y \times Y$.”

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ask $<$ to be a subset of $A\times A$, then a lot of pairs that have nothing to do with $A$ could be part of the relation. So, for example, if you think in the usual order $<$ on $\Bbb R$ (but with extra stuff) then it could be the case that, apart from the "correct" inequalities like $0<1$ and $-7<\pi$ you also have $3< i$, $\Bbb N < 19$, etc. which would be technically correct if you put those pairs in $<$. You obviously don't want that.